# Python guı text insert function result

Tags: python, tkinter

Hello everyone how can insert in gui text  function result of another module. you can see code below:

`modul_1.py`

```py
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import *
import modul_2 

window = tk.Tk()
b = Button(text="çalıştır", command = modul_2.goster)
b.place(x=20, y=20)
window.mainloop()
```

`modul_2.py`

```py
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import messagebox
import modul_1

def goster():
    messagebox.showinfo("deneme","deneme")
    Text1 = tk.Text(window)
    Text1.insert(tk.END, "Bu kısım")
    Text1.place(x=50, y=50)
goster()
```

Comment: The function **goster** is already doing what you've described - inserting a string into the Text-widget. I do not understand what the problem is.

Comment: b = Button(text="çalıştır", command = modul_2.goster)

AttributeError: partially initialized module 'modul_2' has no attribute 'goster' (most likely due to a circular import) here is the problem

Comment: **Please** - in the future include your **entire code ** and **error message(s)**. Otherwise we simply cannot help you. Instead of commenting it as a response, edit your question and insert it there.

Comment: go learn about packages and learn about imports and **don't use `*` when importing**

Comment: sorry ı forgot to add eror message. what is the meaning of eror message?

Comment: also btw you're doing a **circular import** - modules can and should not import one-another!

Comment: @Matiiss Guess it's a bad habit to use those terms interchangeably - thanks for correcting me.

Comment: Could you type correct code ı dont know how to write hence ı typed circular import

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Circular (or cyclic) imports in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/744373/circular-or-cyclic-imports-in-python)

Comment: No doesnt I am junior developer

Comment: @mesyen then you need to take a look at tutorials or read documentation, there are plenty of resources on this issue, you just have to find them

Comment: Beginner tip: Avoid using multiple file that spans two different windows. Instead do everything inside a single file

Answer (score 0):

The better way is to stock the data from the module you want then import it in the desired module .